# load method calls another method at the end in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `Task` with two methods `execute()` and `finish()` as the following:

```java
abstract class Task {
  abstract void execute();

  private void finish() {
    // Do something...
  }
}
```

How can I ensure that the overloaded method `execute()` in subclasses of `Task` **implicitly** calls `finish()` as the last statement?

Comment: Not easily I don't think, but I wonder if we may be barking up the wrong tree, if this might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) in disguise. Please consider telling more details of the overall problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: first of all - it's _private_, how do you expect for it to be called in a different class?

Comment: the qux method have critical code that should be executed when bar finishes. And only Foo should see/call it.

Comment: What if `qux` called `bar`?

Comment: Cant happen. Does make any sense to my problem

Comment: You've got conflicting requirements, then.  If you make qux() private to Foo, and then don't call it in Foo, it's not going to get called.

Comment: Wait... may be it can work... What if I pass a lambda function to qux?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest that in addition to the updates you've done, you take another look at @HovercraftFullOfEels original comment about the XY problem and try to explain what problem you're actually trying to solve here.  It's not clear at all why the [answer posted by stridecolossus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56175007/1361506) isn't sufficient for your needs.

Comment: don't use an abstract class, use composition instead of inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `ExecutorCloseable` class that implements the [`[AutoCloseable]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface, such as:

```
public class ExecutorCloseable extends Foo implements AutoCloseable 
{
  @Override
  public void execute() 
  {
    // ...
  }

  @Override           //this one comes from AutoCloseable
  public void close() //<--will be called after execute is finished
  {
     super.finish();
  }
 }
```

You could call it this way (silly `main()` example):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
     try (ExecutorCloseable ec = new ExecutorCloseable ()) 
     {

        ec.execute();

     } catch(Exception e){
        //...
     } finally {
       //...
    }
 }
```

Hope it makes sense, I can't really know how you call these methods nor how you create the classes. But hey, it's a try : )

For this to work, the `finish()` method on `Foo` should be `protected` or `public` (first one recommended), though.

Comment: I don't think you can call `super.finish()`, since it's a private method.  My IDE says that the finish() is not visible when I try this.

Comment: well, making it protected could do it : ). If his need is getting it private, won't work. Anyway, if he wants finish() to be called from outside (as inside the abstract class would require some wrapping magic), he should make it protected, at least.

Answer (score 9):

I don't believe there is any way of 'forcing' sub-classes to invoke a method but you could try some sort of *template method* approach:

```
abstract class Foo {
  protected abstract void bar();     // <--- Note protected so only visible to this and sub-classes

  private void qux() {
    // Do something...
  }

  // This is the `public` template API, you might want this to be final
  public final void method() {
    bar();
    qux();
  }
}
```

The public `method` is the entry-point and invokes the abstract `bar` and then the private `qux` method, this means that any sub-classes follow the template pattern.  However it's no panacea of course - a sub-class could simply ignore the public `method`.

Comment: this is the only way I can think of.

Comment: In your solution subclasses should explicitly call method(). I dont want it

Comment: @MichaelPacheco: re `"... I don't want it..."` which begs the question of "why?", and what is the overlying problem that is the impetus for this question? Again, as per my comment to the OP, I fear that we may be dealing with an XY Problem -- with trying to solve the wrong problem, but no one can be sure without more background and supporting *concrete* information.

Comment: @MichaelPacheco at least this answer makes _some_ sense, your question and arguments _dont_

Comment: @Eugene: but they *can* if he improves them. But yes, 1+ to this answer.

Comment: @MichaelPacheco In that case, if your abstract class only has a one method then consider making it a functional interface instead and add a static `execute` method that invokes the abstract method and then `qux`, e.g. `interface Foo { void bar(); static void execute(Foo foo) { foo.bar(); qux(); } ... }`

Comment: @stridecolossus you should add that to the answer as an edit IMO